# Are finite index subgroups of inertia closed?

Tags: nt.number-theory, topological-groups, profinite-groups

Let $K$ be a finite extension of the $p$-adic numbers. $G_K$ be its absolute Galois group and $I_K$ the inertia subgroup. Are finite index subgroups of $I_K$ closed in its profinite topology?

By a result of  [Nikolov/Segal](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1631073X03003492) it suffices to show, that inertia is topologically finitely generated.

> What has been proved in the direction of this or the analogous question on wild inertia?

Do the results of Jannsen/Koch/Wingberg on the finite generator rank of the local Galois group help? I couldn't find anything on this and considering its importance, it surely would be mentioned somewhere, if it were always known. So maybe someone has some conditional results?

Comment: Dear Konrad, Let $K_n$ be the degree $n$ unramified extension of $K$.  Then $I_K = I_{K_n}$.  Class field theory shows that $I_{K_n}^{ab} = \mathcal O_{K_n}^{\times}$, whose pro-$p$-part, modulo its torsion subgroup (the $p$th power roots of unity contained in $K_n$), is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_p^{nd}$, if $d$ denotes the degree of $K$ over $\mathbb Q_p$.  Thus $I_K^{\mathrm{wild}}$ admits a surjection onto $\mathbb Z_p^{nd}$ for all $n$, and so is not topologically finitely generated.  Regards, Matthew

Comment: @Emerton: Thank you for your nice comment. Maybe in the light of this http://mathoverflow.net/questions/82177/a-profinite-group-which-is-not-its-own-profinite-completion question and its answers, one can't hope for much more concerning the closedness of finite index normal subgroups. I will think some more about it. Thanks again!

Comment: @Konrad: Refining Emerton's comment, since $I_K$ is the absolute Galois group of a complete discretely-valued field with alg. closed residue field, Serre's geometric local class field theory applies to $I_K$. Thus, the commutative profinite $I_K^{\rm{ab}}$ admits $p$-torsion Hausdorff quotients finite-dimensional over $\mathbf{F}_p$ with arbitrarily large dimension, so it admits a continuous homomorphism onto the countably infinite direct product $P = \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbf{F}_p$. But $P$ has finite-index subgroups that are not closed, so the answer to your question is negative. 

Comment: Oops, when I wrote that the answer to your question is "negative" I overlooked the form in which you posed it.  I should have said that the answer to your question is "affirmative": there *are* finite-index subgroups of $I_K$ that are not closed (for reasons indicated in my preceding comment, since a countably infinite direct product of $\mathbf{F}_p$'s has only countably many closed subgroups of finite index but has uncountable dimension over $\mathbf{F}_p$ and hence has uncountably many finite-index subgroups, so "most" of them are not closed).

Comment: @xuhan, I will accept Chandan's answer, since yours was written as a comment. I will surely have a look at the reference. Thank you for it.

Comment: @Konrad: Chandan's answer is much better than my comments!  :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is another way to see that the wild inertia group $P_K=\mathrm{Gal}(\bar K|T)$ (where $T$ is the maximal tamely ramified extension of $K$ (a finite extension of $\mathbf{Q}_p$) in $\bar K$, an algebraic closure of $K$, is not finitely generated (as a profinite group).  One doesn't need class field theory, only Kummer theory and the fact that a pro-$p$ group $G$ is finitely generated if and only if the $\mathbf{F}_p$-space $G/D$ is finite, where $D$ is the closed subgroup generated by all commutators and all $p$-th powers in $D$.

In the case at hand, $P_K/D=\mathrm{Gal}(T(\root p\of{T^\times})|T)$, and it can be easily seen that the $\mathbf{F}_p$-space $T^\times/T^{\times p}$ is infinite.

Comment: Note that proving that a profinite group is not topologically finitely generated does not imply that there are non-closed finite index subgroups. (Example: $\prod_p(\mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z})^p$ where $p$ ranges over primes is not t.f.g. but finite index subgroups are closed.) But it's indeed true for a pro-$p$-group.

Comment: @YvesCornulier, thanks.  Fortunately the profinite group in question (the wild inertia group) is a pro-$p$-group.